# Как записать данные в определнную часть документа excel

Tags: python, excel

Допустим у меня есть переменная с данными которые нужно перенести в опреленную часть документа
вот сам документ:https://dropmefiles.com/a9NYi
Все ячейки которые отмечены желтым нужно вставить данные переменной. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для этого pandas.
Через `pip install pandas`

https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/500426/

https://habr.com/ru/post/196980/

Comment: А можете конкретно написать ту команду для заполнения данных в определенную ячейку?